# Programmatically setting DynamoDB GSI to be autoscaling

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, autoscaling

I am using `registerScalableTarget` to set my Global Secondary Index as autoscaling. Below is my code. I get no error message whatsoever.

```
var registerScalableTargetForWCU= function(event, callback) {
   var params= {
       ServiceNamespace: "dynamodb", RoleARN: event.roleArn,
       ResourceId: "table/TableName/index/IndexName",
       ScalableDimension: "dynamodb:index:WriteCapacityUnits",
       MinCapacity: 1, MaxCapacity: 2
   };
   applicationautoscaling.registerScalableTarget(params, function(err, res) {
       err ? callback(err) : callback(null, res);
   });
}
```

But on Management Console, the "Auto Scaling" remains unchanged, as shown in screenshot below. [image]

If I were to run `describeScalableTargets`, I get the following though

```
{ ScalableTargets: [ { ServiceNamespace: 'dynamodb',
   ResourceId: 'table/TableName/index/IndexName',
   ScalableDimension: 'dynamodb:index:ReadCapacityUnits',
   MinCapacity: 1,
   MaxCapacity: 1,
   RoleARN: 'RoleARN',
   CreationTime: 2017-08-06T08:32:30.294Z },
 { ServiceNamespace: 'dynamodb',
   ResourceId: 'table/TableName/index/IndexName',
   ScalableDimension: 'dynamodb:index:WriteCapacityUnits',
   MinCapacity: 2,
   MaxCapacity: 10,
   RoleARN: 'RoleARN',
   CreationTime: 2017-08-06T08:32:30.460Z } ] }
```

Is it autoscaling already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For application auto-scaling to work you need a scalable target and [a scaling policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ApplicationAutoScaling.html#putScalingPolicy-property). Seems like the scaling policy is missing in your case. It defines under which circumstances scaling should happen. As it's missing auto-scaling is simply not enabled and therefore not shown in the management console.

The documentation for application auto-scaling also contains information about how it works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html

Comment: I was under the impression that there's no need for a scaling policy. ie, when I 'registerScalableTarget' a dynamo table, it autoscales automatically without me having to define a policy.